# How to get the sum of the numbers from the list

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

After i generate a group of random number from -100 to 100, how do i sum up all the number?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBoxes = new List<TextBox> { TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5 };
    var rand = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
    foreach (var textBox in textBoxes)
        textBox.Text = rand.Next(-100, 100).ToString();
}
```

Comment: You're already looping through the list why not create a local var and then add to it as you loop through them? Or after you do all the setting of the `Text` properties, you'd have to loop through (foreach/Linq) again and sum up the values from the `Text` properties. To be honest I'm not seeing a clear issue, you're asking how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
               var theSum = textBoxes.Sum(x=>int.Parse(x.Text));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to generate the numbers and sum the value.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => rnd.Next(-100, 100)).ToList();

int total = list.Sum();
```

Then fill the TextBoxes from that list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Count; i++)
{
    textBoxes[i].Text = list[i].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one

```
 int a = 0;
 var res = textBoxes.Sum(x => int.TryParse(x, out a)?int.Parse(x):0);
```